# How can i break my own linux kernel

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

I was reading the linux book which says this

> Finally, if you break your kernel or boot loader, you won't be able to
>   get to single-user
>   mode without extra help. You can often boot your system with a kernel
>   from a bootable CD-ROM
>   by passing the root parameter to the CD-ROM's kernel boot loader. Your
>   system might look
>   somewhat strange without your regular kernel, but you should still
>   be able to move files
>   around or perhaps even compile a new kernel to get yourself out of the
>   jam.

Now i want to practically do that and see how i can recompile the broken kernel from cd.

I means  i have the running fine version of centos.
I do something and my system won't boot as kernel gor corrupted.

Now can i recompile the kernel as said in book so that i can bring my system in running state. or my all chnages will be lost and data as well

Answer (score 3):

Simply delete the kernel (or move it somewhere other then /boot) and you will experience the situation described.

Unless you originally compiled your kernel from source there is no reason why you would do that while booted from a CD.  Typically you would just download or reinstall the kernel package, or if you are doing what you are supposed to restore it from your backup.

Comment: Ok i install the centos from distribution cd. all the settings are set and i deleted the kernel.  how can i recompile only kernel with all user home directories as it is

Comment: I tend to strongly favor the Debian/Ubuntu distributions.  I am not sure exactly what packages you need to reinstall or what tools you would use to rebuild the kernel.